# Recursively walk through all connected nodes in a graph

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, graph

I am trying to write a function that finds all nodes that is connected to the given node in a graph **without importing other modules**.

Currently, my setting looks like the following:

```
class Node:
    self.name, self.routes, self.neighbours

class Edge:
    self.nodes, self.distance
```

I have a recursive function:

```
def search_graph(start):
    def aux(start, visited):
        if start in visited:
            return visited
        visited.add(start)
        if set(start.neighbours) < visited:
            return visited
        for node in set(start.neighbours) -visited:
            return visited | aux(node, visited)
    return aux(start, set())
```

I tried some graphs with it, it turns out that when the function reaches some endpoint of a graph, it won't trace back to the last node. For example:
    graph:
        Tokyo - Shanghai - Melbourne - Singapore
With `search_graph(Shanghai)` I can only get `{Shanghai, Melbourne, Singapore}`.

Interestingly, after some search, I find that my function resembles a depth-first-search a lot, still I cannot figure what is wrong with my function.

Thank you!

Comment: The for loop always stops executing after processing the first new unvisited node (since it returns).

Comment: (you probably want to replace it with just a call to aux(node, visited) followed by return visited after the loop, since aux updates the visited set)

Comment: Thank you, by removing the return statement, the function now works as expected! @UriZarfaty